# R package, trying to lapply function to Biostring Views?

Tags: r, lapply, r-s4

First of all, I want to apologize if I am asking stupid questions, I have been only working for 2 days with R but I have to do it for my job.

I am trying to apply a function (calculate a product of matrices indexed by the name of a base pair) and I am using Biostrings to manage big sequences of DNA. I have to "window" these sequences into shorter sequences of 147 bp and apply a function to these shorter sequences.

So here's a MWE of what my code should look like (all this code is mine so it might be wrong, and I still do not understand the difference between = and <-):

```
MyMWEf <- function(seq, MAT){
  #MAT has colnames and rownames "BPs", for example "AG", "TA", etc.
  BPs = Views(seq, start = 1:(length(seq)-1), width = 2)
  BPs = unlist(lapply(BPs,toString)) 
  #With this I get a list of bps ("AG" "TA" etc.)
  AVGs = AVG[BPs, ]
  res=sum(AVGs)
}

MyMWE <- function(seq, MAT){
  seq <- Biostrings::DNAString(seq)
  windows <- Views(seq, start = 1:(length(seq)-146), width = 147)
  res = unlist(lapply(windows, MyMWEf, MAT))
}
```

Now, if I build a package with this and install it and run it, it gives me the following error:

```
 error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'unlist': Error in as.list.default(X) : 
 No method to coerce this S4 class to a vector
```

So I started debugging, and found out that the problem comes in the `lapply` actually: It says `error during wrapup`. More specifically, it seems that the error comes when it tries to do `as.list(windows)`. However, if I do the same but inside the console there is no error! I can `lapply` without problem for example `lapply(windows,length)` or even `lapply(windows,MyMWEf,MAT)` and everything works just fine (if I defined the function MyMWEf in the console), also if inside the console I write `as.list(windows)' it works.

If anybody could give me some insight in what am I doing wrong I would very much appreciate it!

Thank you

edited after narrowing down a bit (as.list problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symptom you see is that the function works fine in an interactive session, but not within a package NAMESPACE.

This is usually because of an error in your package NAMESPACE file, and in particular you need to have in the DESCRIPTION part of your package the line

```
Imports: Biostrings
```

and in the NAMESPACE file something along the lines of

```
importMethodsFrom(Biostrings, as.list)
```

If you make heavy use of a package, then it might make more sense to have instead

```
import(Biostrings)
```

The [Biocondcutor](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/mailform/) mailing list would be an appropriate place to post follow-up questions about using [Biostrings](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html).

Comment: Thank you! I already had `import(Biostrings)` in the Namespace but not the DESCRIPTION part. However, it is too slow yet, so time to learn how to use `.Call` now! And thank you as well for the link, I will use it from now on.

Comment: These string operations are fast when formulated properly, so ask for guidance on your algorithm on the Bioc mailing list (no subscription required); you'll get expert advice.